# Extract data using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, let

I'd like to obtain these informations from the following xml:

The largest number of values outside the healthy range in a single exam.
A value $val outside the healty range is :  $val < MinVal or $val > MaxVal

The xml is the following:

```
<MedicalCenter>
  <Patient Id="1">
    ...
  </Patient>
  <Exam PatientId="1">
   ...
    <Outcome>
      <Parameter>A</Parameter>
      <Value>90</Value>
      <MinVal>100</MinVal>
      <MaxVal>150</MaxVal>
    </Outcome>
    <Outcome>
      <Parameter>B</Parameter>
      <Value>15</Value>
      <MinVal>1</MinVal>
      <MaxVal>20</MaxVal>
    </Outcome>
    <Outcome>
      <Parameter>C</Parameter>
      <Value>1</Value>
      <MinVal>1</MinVal>
      <MaxVal>5</MaxVal>
    </Outcome>
    <Doctor>Stack Overflow</Doctor>
   </Exam>
   <Patient Id="2">
    ...
  </Patient>
  <Exam PatientId="2">
    ...
    <Outcome>
      <Parameter>A</Parameter>
      <Value>190</Value>
      <MinVal>100</MinVal>
      <MaxVal>150</MaxVal>
    </Outcome>
    <Outcome>
      <Parameter>C</Parameter>
      <Value>10</Value>
      <MinVal>1</MinVal>
      <MaxVal>5</MaxVal>
    </Outcome>
    <Doctor>Stack Overflow</Doctor>
   </Exam>
</MedicalCenter>
```

My solution is the following, but I keep getting the following error:

```
declare function local:outRange( $x as element() ) as xs:boolean{
  if( $x/value < MinValue and $x/value > MaxValue )
  then( false )
  else( true )
};

declare function local:numOk( $exam as element()+ ) as xs:integer{
  let $ok := $exam/Outcome
  where local:outRange($ok) = true
  return count($ok)
};

let $res := local:numOk( doc("myXml.xml")//Exam )
return max( $res )
```

Also with this code I haven't reach the solution.
I really don't know where is the problem.
I've also removed the return from the function true, false but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Sample XML to test the XQuery against, and the expected output given that XML, would be very helpful

Comment: @har07 I've added a sample of XML and tried to execute the original one but I still haven't reach the solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `return` here. This is one possible way to declare the `outRange()` function to return boolean value `true` if `Value` is less than `MinVal` *or* greater than `MaxVal`, and return boolean value `false` otherwise :

```
declare function local:outRange( $x as element() ) as xs:boolean{
  boolean($x/Value < $x/MinVal or $x/Value > $x/MaxVal)
};
```

And then `numOk()` function can be simplified like so :

```
declare function local:numOk( $exam as element()+ ) as xs:integer{
  count($exam/Outcome[local:outRange(.)])
};
```

Notice that `.` references current context node i.e `local:outRange(.)` means call `outRange()` function passing current `Outcome` context node as parameter.

---

See the demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/33c21c43cc78e72688dc52e7bfbadd43

output (notice the number **`2`** at the end) : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>2`